# How to add a button in tkinter toplevel() window

Tags: python, tkinter

I am getting below error when I am trying to add button in toplevel.

```
AttributeError: 'Toplevel' object has no attribute 'Button'
```

Part of Code:

```
def open_window():  
    win=Toplevel(root)  
    win.geometry("400x400")
    win.title("Table Related Information")
    win.grab_set() 
    btn=win.Button(topframe,Text="Fetch")
    btn.pack()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot create the button with `win.Button` because creating a button is not done through a `Toplevel` method but with a tkinter class. The correct syntax is:

```
win = tk.Toplevel(root)
btn = tk.Button(win, text='fetch')
```

where I used the import statement `import tkinter as tk`. This way you clearly see that both the `Toplevel` and the `Button` are classes belonging to the `tkinter` module. The parent of the button is given as the first argument when you create it.

Also, notice that the `text=` keyword argument should not be capitalized.